# VisualStudio remotebuild fails with error - 1

Tags: ios, xcode, visual-studio, cordova, tools-for-apache-cordova

I've been using remotebuild to build my ApacheCordova app made in Visual Studio, but started failing with the next error on the output:

```
...
1>  Wrote iOS Plist: /Users/UC/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/503/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/myAppName/myAppName-Info.plist
1>  Checking config.xml for saved plugins that haven't been added to the project
1>  Saving ios@4.1.1 into platforms.json
1>  No scripts found for hook "after_platform_add".
1>  Failed to build app for buildNumber 503:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Error: Remote build error from the build server Build failed with error - 1
1>  Error Remote build error from the build server Build failed with error  - {1}
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have made no mayor changes to the application, few days ago i compiled with no problems, the mac uses OSX El Capitan vers. 10.11.6 with xcode 8.

I tried to look for the error - 1 but it doesn't seem to exist, if someone could give me insights on this problem i would really appreciate it, thanks in advance!

Edit: I started a completely new blank cordova proyect on Visual Studio, shows the same error when i try to compile it, might have something to do with the xcode?

Comment: You need to go to Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run, and change MSBuild Options to Detailed. Both. So you could see a more detailed explanation about the error.

Comment: Just did that and keeps showing the same information about that error `Error: Remote build error from the build server Build failed with error - 1`

Comment: You can also look in your terminal window on mac to find new messages.

Comment: The mac Terminal shows nothing out of the ordinary, in fact seems like the remotebuild finishes the build successfully from that side, or at least doesn't show any error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Fabio for the interest. Solved by installing the cordova globally on the compiling machine (installed 6.1.1) and clearing the ~/.taco_home/node_modules folder, there is an open issue in the remotebuild git about this problem and looks like it will have an update to correct it soon, hope this helps someone!

Comment: Hi @Orion390, I too am having this issue. Can you please provide a link about the remotebuild git you were talking about. Also ~/.taco_home/node_modules folder is on the remote machine? Thanks in advance

Comment: This is where i got the solution from https://github.com/Microsoft/remotebuild/issues/26 (posted near the end by AnBucyk), it consists in deleting that folder in the remote machine and install cordova globally on the compiling machine by npm install -g cordova@6.1.1 (i installed 6.1.1 because is the one my visual studio uses) and that resolved the problem